# Need guidance on designing a custom pie chart UI in Flutter: UI layout issue

Tags: flutter

[image: ui]

I have list of expense model data, which will be placed around of pie chart and from pie chart to that expense icon there will be a straight line.
**How can i achieve this kind of UI with flutter?**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this might be to use a custom painter and draw the lines as paths. The coordinates of where to draw them gets really tricky once you factor in different screen sizes, or scaling. It also gets really tricky to manage because lines could easily have to intersect the pie chart and it might look really messy (for example in your image if the line that goes to the shirt 5% actually needed to go to go to the phone). You could come up with a way to shift all the icons around so they will never overlap, but from a UX perspective that may not be the best since things are not always in the same place.

Other options I can think of that avoid this are:

1. color code the segment and the icon. When you tap either, it highlights the icon with a box around it or something, and the pie slice expands (see this package for pie charts https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart)
2. When you tap an icon or a pie slice, the whole pie chart could rotate so the slice and the icon are close and then draw the line between them. Still some math and animations to rotate the pie chart, but the coordinates for the lines would be a lot easier, and no lines would ever need to cross over the pie chart.

Maybe there a a good way to handle drawing the lines as you originally asked, but I can't think of anything right now